# Migration from three.js r52 to r58 issue

Tags: three.js

I'm using three.js and I would like to migrate from r52 to r58 but I have problems with textures and geometry. Here is the part that I have a problem with:
https://github.com/pasquelin/EnigmaCube/blob/dev/js/class/Three.Map.js#L255

Do you have an idea for my migration to keep my different textures on my different faces.

PS: I'm not super strong in 3D and I use google translate to communicate better lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating from r49 to r58, I had the same problem. When you're in front of this kind of problem, just take a look at the library's changelog (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration#r52--r53) you'll notice that in the r53, the texture system was modified:

> Geometry no longer has a materials property. MeshFaceMaterials usage is now like this: new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterials( [ material1, material2 ] ) )

So,

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(width, height, largeur, 1, 1, 1, materials), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
```

become:

```
var cb = new THREE.CubeGeometry( width, height, largeur, 1, 1, 1 );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( cb, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(faces) );
```

/!\ Take note that THREE.MeshFaceMaterial is singular, althought it is plural in the changelog

Comment: Stack Overflow requires posting in English. This appears to be an answer, so if you translate it it should be OK.

Comment: If you not translate it, everything will not be OK.